# local variable 'nheigth' referenced before assignment on python

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I am running the following python function:

```
def imageprepare(argv):

    im = Image.open(argv).convert('L')
    width = float(im.size[0])
    height = float(im.size[1])
    newImage = Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255)) 

    if width > height: 
        nheight = int(round((20.0/width*height),0))
        if (nheigth == 0):
            nheigth = 1  
        img = im.resize((20,nheight), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight)/2),0))
        newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop))
    else:
        nwidth = int(round((20.0/height*width),0)) #
        if (nwidth == 0):
            nwidth = 1
        img = im.resize((nwidth,20), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth)/2),0))
        newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4))

    tv = list(newImage.getdata())

    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv] 
    return tva
```

It's giving the error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nheigth' referenced before assignment.

I am running this on conda environment and using python 3.6.

Please help me on this. I am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already spotted by @Falko, you have a typo in the variable that you declare as `nheight` then use as `nheigth`.

Python being a dynamic language with no mandatory declaration of variables, this kind of error is not easy to spot before runtime without proper tools.

I suggest you to use a proper Python IDE such as PyCharm which will spot those errors for you as you type.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo: `nheigth` vs. `nheight`.